# wordpress: change wp_title with variable from another function

Tags: wordpress

i would change the page title from a wordpress plugin site. the name comes from a function:

```
function subPage() {
   $content = 'blabla';
   $subPageTitle = 'Plugin Sub Page Dynamic'; 
   return $content;
}
```

and the simple function for replace wp_title:

```
function wp_plugin_page_title($subPageTitle) {
   $siteTitle = $subPageTitle;
   return $siteTitle;
}
add_filter('wp_title', wp_plugin_page_title);
```

my problem is now: how i get the variable $subPageTitle in the function wp_plugin_page_title()?

Thanks a lot for ANY help!

EDIT: the code was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
function subPage() {
    $subPage = new stdClass();
    $subPage->content = 'blabla';
    $subPage->subPageTitle = 'Plugin Sub Page Dynamic'; 
    return $subPage;
}

function wp_plugin_page_title($subPageTitle) {
   $siteTitle = $subPageTitle . " " . subPage()->subPageTitle;
   return $siteTitle;
}
add_filter('wp_title', wp_plugin_page_title);
```

Then you get the value by calling subPage()

```
echo subPage()->subPageTitle;
```

If you print_r the subpage you will see:
stdClass Object ( [content] => blabla [subPageTitle] => Plugin Sub Page Dynamic )

Any values that are inside a function, they are encapsulated values if you need to reach them outside that function or you return them in an array or in an object.

Comment: i replaced the code in my question with a better code to understand my problem.

Comment: Lets make it simpler, can you tell me what your trying to do?

Comment: i wrote a plugin that replace a shortcode with content from the plugin. the plugin create dynamically subpages. every subpage must have a unique site title (subsite1, subsite2, ...)
the site title is generated in the function subPage. To replace the site title i must use 'addfilter('wp_title', wp_plugin_page_title);'

my problem is: how i get the site title from the function subPage to wp_plugin_pge_title?